# Reactive charts with Meteor : d3charts , Hightcharts , ChartJS , other?

Tags: d3.js, meteor, charts, highcharts, chart.js

I am trying to choose the right technology for making reactive charts with Meteor.

I need to make reactive pie charts and then later on line charts where the the database changes in real time and the charts would be updated automatically. I am using Meteor JS as a backend.

Which charts can be used for this purpose - highcharts , d3 charts , chartjs , meteor charts or any other ? Also what is the basic difference between using these charts with Meteor?

I am a newbie in both charts and Meteor and haven't worked with either of them before.

I know that there are some existing questions that are similar to this one, but none of them exactly ask the same thing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think there is a right answer to this question, it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: "Are there any good tutorials for the same?" is O/T as you are asking for off-site resources. And it's still opinion based, just not as much as before.

Answer (score 5):

**In my opinion**, I prefer ChartJS. I've used it personally, and I really like it.

You can download the official ChartJS Atmosphere package from [here](https://atmospherejs.com/chart/chart). You can also add the Meteor package with `meteor add chart:chart`

You can certainly make your pie chart reactive and update in real-time. I personally did this by abstracting the actual drawing of the graph in a separate function called `renderChart()` which essentially creates the pie chart.

Then, in your graph template's render function, you can add the `observeChanges()` with your data collection.

```
Template.piechart.rendered = function() {
    renderChart();
    YourDataCollection.observeChanges({
        added: function() {
            renderChart();
        },
        changed: function() {
            renderChart();
        }
    });
}
```

As others have mentioned, this is a very subjective answer, so please figure out which library you'd like to use. But **in my opinion** the above method worked best for me. Hope that helps! And let me know if you need help getting started.

Comment: it is not working for me